# Options trading and arbitrage

Tags: options, call-options, put-options, arbitrage

Near market closing time on a given day, you lose access to stock prices, but some
European call and put prices for a stock are available as follows:
[image: Optionsprices]

All six options have the same expiration date.
After reviewing the information above, X tells Y and Z that no arbitrage
opportunities can arise from these prices.

Y disagrees with X. She argues that one could use the following portfolio to
obtain arbitrage profit: Long one call option with strike price 40; short three call options with strike price 50; lend $1; and long some calls with strike price 55.

Z also disagrees with X. He claims that the following portfolio, which is
different from Y’s, can produce arbitrage profit: Long 2 calls and short 2 puts
with strike price 55; long 1 call and short 1 put with strike price 40; lend $2; and short some calls and long the same number of puts with strike price 50.

Which of the following statements is true?

(A) Only X is correct.

(B) Only Y is correct.

(C) Only Z is correct.

(D) Both Y and Z  are correct.

(E) None of them is correct.

Answer:  I got the answer to this question and I accepted the answer provided.

Comment: Please, we are not here to do your homework for you. At least show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: The most basic arb is a conversion (there are others).  Hint: **Call - Put = Price of underlying - PV(Strike)**.  If the left side of the equation (call minus put price) is different than the right side of the equation, a potential conversion arbitrage opportunity exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not finance expert. But answer to this question is (D) Both Y and Z are correct.

Because, After looking at the Y and Z's portfolios, we can conclude that call and put options prices are not arbitrage-free. And for that purpose, we don't need current stock price.

### Y'S PORTFOLIO

[image: Y]

### Z'S PORTFOLIO

[image: Z]